# How should I obtain the relation for $P(A)$?

Tags: probability-theory

It is given that $P(A/B)=0.4$ and $P(A/B^C)=0.6$ then :

(a)$0\le P(A)\le 0.4$

(b)$P(A)=0.5$

(c)$0.6\le P(A)\le 1$

(d)$0.4\le P(A)\le 0.6$

I know $P(A/B)=\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}$ , so $P(A/B^{C})=\frac{P(A\cap B^C)}{P(B^C)}$.

I am not getting what should we use here.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: (d) is the right answer. You have come up with examples to show that the other three may fail. But you should make an effort before you can expect a complete answer.

Comment: Since it is not mentioned whether A and B are independent events or not, I can use the case when A and B are independent events, which will eliminate the options B and C, since for independent events $P(A/B)=P(A)$. Am I right? Can I eliminate the option A too, in some way..?

Comment: @mathstudent it doesn’t make sense to use independence here; in fact, $A$ and $B$ can never be independent because that’s would imply $A$ and $B^C$ also being independent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that

$$
0.4 = P(A\mid B) = \frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)} \le \frac{P(A)}{P(B)}
$$

and

$$
0.6 = P(A\mid B^C) = \frac{P(A\cap B^C)}{P(B^C)} \le \frac{P(A)}{P(B^C)} = \frac{P(A)}{1-P(B)}.
$$

Hence, $P(A)\ge 0.4P(B)$ and $P(A)\ge 0.6-0.6P(B)$. In order for this to hold for arbitrary event $B$, we have $P(A)\ge 0.4$ and $P(A)\ge 0.6$ from the two inequalities.